# Verb+koto+mo soshite Verb+koto+mo nai. Should both words with mo particles be affected by nai at the end?

Tags: particles, particle-も, scope

Ok, here are the lyrics from the idolmaster song called Nation Blue. You can see full lyrics on the imas wiki here: http://www.project-imas.com/wiki/Nation_Blue

The song is pretty hard for a novice like me, but the part I have a question about is this:

> 佇むことも　そして振り返ることも無く
>
> キミの近く　そう　付いていきたいんだ

And the way I see it, the first line should be pretty much the same as

> 佇むことの無く　そして振り返ることの無く

And my translation is:

```
Without loitering/standing still and without looking back,
I want to go after you and be very close to you.
```

As far as I know that is how "~mo ~mo verb" should work. The verb at the end should be applied to all words with mo before it, isn't it?

But the translation on the wiki says otherwise:

```
Stopping for a moment and then not looking back,
```

To be honest I'd write it off as a mistake on wiki's part, but my acquaintance with N2 claims wiki's version as well, therefore I'm really confused now. Do I misunderstand the basics of ~mo usage? Or is there anything else I'm missing? No matter how I look at it, the sentence becomes extremely strange if you go with the wiki's translation. I mean 無く is in adverb form, so it should be a description of how she wants to go after him (or am I wrong here as well?).

So I repeat the question. Should 無く here affect both 佇むことも and 振り返ることも or only 振り返ることも?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right and the wiki is wrong.

It's most natural to assume multiple ～も repeated on the same level to be parallel construction, and they all connect to what comes after the last one.

See [the translation of 雨ニモマケズ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ame_ni_mo_Makezu) below:

> 雨ニモマケズ *not losing to the rain*
>   風ニモマケズ *not losing to the wind*
>   雪ニ**モ**夏ノ暑サニ**モ**マケヌ *not losing to the snow **nor** to summer's heat*

There is chance, however, to interpret the two も in the lyrics don't belong to the same level, thus they aren't parallel. But it doesn't make sense in this line if you take this reading.

If 佇むことも isn't parallel with 振り返ることも, then it must find another predicate to connect. Consequently, it should be an argument of 付いていきたいんだ. But since the noun phrase has nothing before も, it's assumed that the underlying case of the phrase is either が (subject) or を (object), and neither could have a decent meaning.

---

**PS**

> 佇むことの無く　そして振り返ることの無く

～ことのなく is not a natural phrasing. Usually this expression is fixed in the form ～ことなく to mean "without doing", with no intervening particle.

> Without loitering/standing still and without looking back,

佇む has no meaning "loiter". I mean, it [apparently has in dictionaries](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/136779/meaning/m0u/),
but the usage became obsolete centuries ago. Today the word only has the definition "stay at the same place for a while (standing)".